# How to set airflow `http_conn_id` with a param?

Tags: airflow

Running Airflow 2.2.2

I would like to parametrize the `http_conn_id` using the DAG input parameters as such:

```
with DAG(params={'api': 'my-api-id'}) as dag:

  post_op = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='post_op',
    endpoint='custom-end-point',
    http_conn_id='{{ params.api }}',  # <- this doesn't get filled correctly
    dag=dag)
```

Where `my-api-id` is set in the Airflow `Connections`.

However, when executing, the operator evaluates `http_conn_id` as '{{ params.api }}'.

I'm suspecting this is not possible - or is an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow operators do not render all the fields, they render only the fields which are listed in the attribute `template_fields`. For the operator [SimpleHttpOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/http/operators/http.py#L30), you have only the fiels:

```py
    template_fields: Sequence[str] = (
        'endpoint',
        'data',
        'headers',
    )
```

To get around the problem, you can create a new class which extend the official operator, and just add the extra fields you want to render:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator


class MyHttpOperator(SimpleHttpOperator):
    template_fields = (
        *SimpleHttpOperator.template_fields,
        'http_conn_id'
    )


with DAG(
    dag_id='http_dag',
    start_date=datetime.today(),
    params={'api': 'my-api-id'}
) as dag:
    post_op = MyHttpOperator(
        task_id='post_op',
        endpoint='custom-end-point',
        http_conn_id='{{ params.api }}',
        dag=dag
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! thats along the path I ended up going. Template fields clarifies things better!